# Visual studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

Так как не имею опыт работы в VS, при установке задался вопросом: Какие основные компоненты требуется для разработки на языке C#?
Буду благодарен, если кто-нибудь ответит.

Comment: Ставьте все что вам теоретически может пригодиться, в любом случае вы всегда сможете доустановить недостающие компаненты.

Comment: В VS 2017 инсталятор сделали удобным, простым для новичков и довольно гибким для профессионалов, все пункты описаны на русском языке. Для вас достаточно просто отметить "Разработка классических приложений .NET" и "Разработка приложений для универсальной платформы Windows", все основное что нужно инсталлятор установит сам.